# Mean amount of button pushes to get all the numbers from an evenly distributed generator

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let's imagine a generator that gives you one of the numbers from $[1; n]$, each with probability $1/n$, whenever you push a button. What is the mean amount of button pushes you need to get all numbers from $1$ to $n$?

I've considered using a Markov chain and computing its absorption time, I couldn't compute the fundamental matrix for this chain.

Comment: This is a rephrasing of the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you have already seen $k$ of the $n$ numbers, the probability that the next number is new is $1-\frac kn$, hence the expected number of button pushes to learn the next number is $\frac1{1-\frac kn}$.